# Replacing two consecutive cell in an array with one cell

Tags: c#, arrays

I was just asking if there is a simple way of doing this.
i.e. Replacing two consecutive cell with one cell having different value.

For ex: - if my array =[0,3,1,2,3,4], and i want to replace index 0,and 1 with the value 5 
to become like this array=[5,1,2,3,4]

Can you guys suggest some simple way for doing this.
i do this code but there is something wrong:

```
    int J = 0;
            if (max != 1)
            {
                for (int iii = 0; iii < output.Length -1; iii++)
                    {
                        if ((output[iii] == imax) && (output[iii + 1] == jmax))
                        {
                            temp = temp + 1;
                            output[J] = Convert.ToByte(temp);
                            J = J + 1;
                            iii = iii + 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            output[J] = output[iii];
                            J = J + 1;
                            output[J] = output[iii + 1];
                        }

                    }
            }
```

because when i want to check the 2 consecutive index ,i want to pass them to the anther 2 index

Comment: Simple way is to use a list rather than an array then you can remove items as well as replacing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care about performance you want to do as little operations that can harm performance. Try this extension method:

```
public static int[] ReplaceConsecutiveCells(this int[] array, int startIndex, int replaceWith)
{
    int[] targetArray = new int[array.Length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < startIndex)
        {
            targetArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        else if (i == startIndex)
        {
            targetArray[i] = replaceWith;
        }
        else if (i == startIndex + 1)
        {
            // no action
        }
        else
        {
            targetArray[i - 1] = array[i];
        }
    }

    return targetArray;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
array = array.ReplaceConsecutiveCells(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> list = array.ToList();
list.RemoveRange(0,2);
list.Insert(0, 5);
array = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Array.Reverse(array);
Array.Resize(ref array, 5);
Array.Reverse(array);
array[0] = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do
        {
            RNG_NXT =RNG +1;   
        for (int iii = 0; iii <Nold -1; iii++)
                    {
                        if ((output[iii] == imax) && (output[iii + 1] == jmax))
                        {
                            output[J] = Convert.ToByte(RNG_NXT);
                            J = J + 1;
                            iii = iii + 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            output[J] = output[iii];
                            J = J + 1;
                        }
                   }
            RNG++;            
        }
while( RNG < RNG_MAX) ;
```

Comment: This is just the code from your question, unchanged. Why did you put that as an answer?

Comment: sorry ,i,m adding just do while so in each time of a loop i find two consecutive number with most Repetition

Comment: Ah, okay. In that case, I don't see how this answers your question, but I think that may be because I'm having trouble figuring out what your question is really about. More importantly though, I also don't see how this loop ever terminates, unless it never loops at all: neither `RNG` nor `RNG_MAX` ever change during the loop, so if the condition is true once, it will always continue to be true.